# How can I select from multiple numbers to dial from with button click?

Tags: java, android

I currently have an app that has a 'call' button. I want to know if there is a way to list different numbers in a popup to dial from. For example, I am close the border and this app will be used on both sides. The target number is from Mexico. If the caller is dialing from Mexico, they can dial it like this: (654)456-3445, but if you are dialing from the US, you would have to dial like this: 01152(653)456-3445. How can I prompt the user to select which format they want to dial, or is there a way that they can select where they are calling from in that prompt and have the app dial accordingly? Or if anyone has any better suggestions, that would be great!

This is how I am currently dialing the number but I want them to be able to select:

```
call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:011526544567890"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
});
```

---

EDIT: HERE IS WHAT I ENDED UP USING.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    String number;

    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryCode();

    if (countryCode.equalsIgnoreCase("us")) {
        number = "tel:011526531232233";
    } else {
        number = "tel:6531232233";
    }

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the java.util.Locale class and automatically add a phone number prefix which is dependent upon whatever country the application is running in.

Your Country:

> System.out.println(java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry());

Comment: Thank you! Although I didn't exactly use what you mentioned, it helped me find another way to do it. I will edit my question and add my solution to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Before calling the ACTION_DIAL intent, you can have a dialog that will display the formatted number that they will call (with a call button which when clicked will call the ACTION_DIAL intent). From the dialog, they can update the format, either via EditText.

Alternatively, you can check user location and update the dialog with the number formatted already based on location.